# Character ﷼ can not be pasted in front of a number

Tags: html

I can't paste the character `﷼` (Riyal currency) in front of a number:

`1﷼`

It's even impossible to paste it between 2 numbers, it's pasted at the end:

`11﷼`

There aren't any problems if you try to paste it in front of a letter:

`﷼a`

Does anybody know what happens and how I can do it?

Comment: no affect on me

Comment: When I try to paste it in Chrome's omnibox, the character is visible before the number, but shift + left arrow properly selects it. I don't have any issue when pasting in Google's website search bar.

Comment: @Seblor you can reproduce it from the top search bar in current page.

Comment: Since your question is tagged HTML I assume you have some HTML code exemple to provide. Or maybe it is when you type text in an <input> ? I think it would be very helpful if you add those precisions into your question post.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is an interesting question. The more general case is pasting a RTL character (right to left) in a LTR format.

In addition to the character you need a LTR unicode mark:

`&#x200e;`

See also: https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H34.html

Comment: In case an example is needed, here it is in a sentence: `I have &#65020;&#x200e;100 but I wish I had more.` (`&#65020;` is the html code for the rial). [Renders like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzJ4y.png)

Answer (score 7):

Probably related to the compilation direction. If you want to use it in HTML, I think following code can works for you

```html
<bdo dir="ltr"> ﷼ 1</bdo>
```

Comment: for more detail about bi-directional override tag https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_bdo.asp

Answer (score 3):

in html tag better do like this :

```
<html lang="fa">
```

in meta tag use this :

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

and in this case for example i used `table` and then `RTL` (right to left) in `dir` attribute :

```
<table dir="rtl" border="1" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#A2F0BE">قیمت</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>4,840,000 ﷼</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

and also check this out ,for example :

```
 HTML Entity (Decimal)  &#65020;
```

```html
<p dir=rtl> 1000 &#65020;</p>
```

```
HTML Entity (Hexadecimal)   &#xFDFC;
```

```html
<p dir="rtl">1000 &#xFDFC;</p>
```